# Displaying values of excel Workbook in DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I need some help displaying values of excel in datagridview.
i manage to display values but some of the values are missing(columns,and values of rows).i have 1000 rows in my excel file and the data grid view is only displaying 333 items in it. and i have 148 number of columns but it only display some of it. can someone tell me what the problem is.

here is my code:

```
     public partial class MainBagsakan : Form
     [enter image description here][1]
      String WOmain=@"C:\Users\tjjtabije\Desktop\TestExcelUpdater\TestUnoREFARM.xlsx";
      private string Excel07ConString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\t-jjtabije\\Desktop\\TestExcelUpdater\\TestUnoREFARM.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text'";
      private void WorkOrderTab()
     {

        string filePath = Path.GetFullPath(WOmain);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
        string conStr, sheetName;
        conStr = string.Empty;

        //Get the name of the First Sheet.
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(Excel07ConString))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                DataTable dtExcelSchema = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(Excel07ConString))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * [" +sheetName+ "]";
                    con.Open();
                    oda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    oda.Fill(dt);
                    con.Close();

                    //Populate DataGridView.
                    WorkLoadDisp.DataSource = dt;
                    label1.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should set a break point at `WorkLoadDisp.DataSource = dt;` and check whats in `dt`. I am guessing you may not be getting all the data you think you should. Just a guess.

Comment: Hi Sir. what do yo mean by breakpoint ? please explain further im sorry im new to programming. and yes im not getting all the data on the excel. thank you for the help

Comment: If you are using an IDE like Visual Studio, you can set a breakpoint on a line of code. (rightClick-> Breakpoint) When you run the code it will stop executing at the breakpoint. When it stops you can examine your variables like `dt` to see what they contain. Idea being that you point to the `DataGridView` not displaying properly, and that may well be, however, before looking for a `DataGridView` problem… make sure the data you are getting from excel is correct. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: i have done the breakpoint and i cant read what it is saying .

Comment: I would recommend looking in the help section. In VS there are tabs at the bottom when debugging to show local variable values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unnecessary to open and close the connection twice as you are with the two separate using clauses.  The first one simply gets the name of a worksheet sort of, as a named range could also be returned. I simply put all the code into a single group and it seems to work as expected.

Added a missing `FROM` to the select statement:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";
```

The changes I made are below...

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(Excel07ConString)) {
  using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand()) {
    using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter()) {
      cmd.Connection = con;
      con.Open();
      DataTable dtExcelSchema = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
      sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
      DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
      cmd.Connection = con;
      cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";
      //con.Open();
      oda.SelectCommand = cmd;
      oda.Fill(dt);
      con.Close();
      //Populate DataGridView.
      WorkLoadDisp.DataSource = dt;
      label1.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad you got it working. As I said be careful for named ranges as that is what was returned with line: `sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();` Create a named range in your worksheet and see if it doesn't get returned with the line above. Just a heads up.

Comment: Ok sir Thanks for the heads up :)